# Issue with Response time from Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, ios8, response-time

Currently I am working with an iOS app which has some features to work with File datatype. I need  to upload the images on Parse and also download the images from parse. Here I am facing issues with the response time that parse gives me.

When I upload a single image chosen from gallery in iOS device, it takes too much time to respond back. Likely if I am uploading a single image it takes around more than 1 minute to upload and respond back. The same thing is happening with downloading the images from parse server.

Can anyone please suggest me what should I do in order to improve these response time? Like do I need to pay something to get faster response? Or this is normal response time provided by parse for all accounts like paid and free.

I am using below code for uploading image,

```
//Upload a new picture
    NSData *pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.selectedImage);
    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"img" data:pictureData];
    [registrationData setObject:file forKey:@"image"];

    [registrationData saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {

        } else {

        }
    }];
```

Can anyone please suggest me the way to get faster response?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: What's the size of the images?

Comment: @Larme I choose image from iPhone gallery.

Comment: my suggestion would be to upload to Parse your HD image, and use cloud code to build dynamically some resized and optimized images. Check here : http://blog.parse.com/announcements/new-cloud-modules-for-images-and-users/

Comment: @Toucouleur Alright. Will see it.

Comment: If you need sample code, I can provide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to Parse call multiple nested call to upload image(s) so its better to

- use png image
- scale image before uploading
- type of account may of one of issue (free / paid)

hope It helps